# Adding link to a mobile message string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I have a URL in a variable named `url_sale`,
I want to add url_sale in a string as a URL but am not able to achieve it
Here is my code

```
base_url = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('web.base.url')
url_sale = base_url + '/web#id=%s&view_type=form&model=%s' % (record.id, record._name)
vals = {'mobile': empoyee.mobile_phone,
        'message_type': 'message',
        'message': f"""
                        Quotation approval request

                        Hello Approvers,

                        Quotation approval {record.name} has been raised by {record.user_id.name}.

                        Please review and approve or reject (with reason given) this quotation.

                        {url_sale}
                    """
                }
```

inside the dict `vals` for the key `message` when i pass a static URL like `https://www.goindigo.in/bookings/flight-select.html` its working, but when I pass through a variable for dynamic URl it's passing as a string.

actual output:

```
Quotation approval request

                    Hello Approvers,

                    Quotation approval S00029 has been raised by Mitchell Admin.

                    Please review and approve or reject (with reason given) this quotation.

                    https://www.goindigo.in/bookings/flight-select.html
```

Expected Output:

[image: ExPected Output Image]

The Difference between the Expected and Actual output is the "link", I need it in clickable.

Comment: Could you post actual output and expected output? Can't figure out from the description what you need exactly.

Comment: If you insert something to a string it will be a string. Are you sure the url shouldn't be in another key?

Comment: I have Updated the Question with actual and expected output, you can check @Gameplay

Comment: Wait...this is exactly the same from python's POV. Are we missing something? The url has been inserted to the string. What you are showing is some sort of front end, which might not have anything to do with python or I still don't understand something

Comment: how could be, when i try to add a static URL it comes as a clickable format, but when I try to add a variable for dynamic URL it considers as a string

Comment: I guess the difference is whether your Markdown interpreter is able to recognize the final part of the string as a URL or not. As Gameplay said, this has nothing to do with the Python code.

Comment: Would be interessting to know what you are doing with `vals` afterwards. Could you add that?

Comment: I am passing it to a txt field in odoo @CZoellner

Comment: Odoo does support Markdown, so you can use this syntax to format the URL within your string: https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links

Comment: Might be silly, but in the string at the end of the url, have you tried adding a new line or an empty space?

Comment: What type of field is the final output for? If it's html, then the deleted answer - which you probably can't see :D - would be correct. Use HTML code like anchors (`<a href="your_url">the link text or the url again</a>`).

Comment: type of field for the final output.... its actually I am sending to whatsapp APi.... but I am creating the record in a model and storing the message in a text field... @CZoellner

Comment: yeh i have tried that @Arne result is the same

Comment: yeah john if i give a new line still it takes as a string @JohnGardounis

Answer (score 1):

Try formulating the url as an html link:

```
my_string = f"<a href='{url_sale}'>{url_sale}</a>"
```